How can I retrieve RDP files for an Azure Virtual Desktop session using the Desktop Virtualization APIs in a C# .NET application?
I'm trying to implement functionality in my C# .NET application that retrieves RDP files for an Azure Virtual Desktop session, similar to how the Remote Desktop client retrieves them. Specifically, I need to programmatically access RDP file details, such as the session host, username, and connection details, to generate RDP files dynamically for users.
I have already authenticated using Azure Identity, but I’m not sure how to use the Desktop Virtualization APIs to fetch the RDP file or its equivalent session details.
Could someone guide me on how to retrieve or generate the RDP file programmatically using the Azure Virtual Desktop APIs in .NET? Any examples or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
API Doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/desktopvirtualization/?view=rest-desktopvirtualization-2024-04-03
